# Dual Linear Program and Simplex Method

Tags: linear-programming, simplex-method

[image]

To find the dual for this linear program, I first represent $y = (y+)-(y-)$ to make sure that every decision variable is greater than or equal to $0$. Then I split the second constraint into
\begin{align}
2x + 0.5y &\le 5 \\
-2x - 0.5y &\le -5.
\end{align}
Then I write out a dual linear program which is a minimizing program with three variables. It's like:
$$\min Z = 4a + 5b - 5c$$
Subject to

\begin{align}
a + 2b - 2c &\ge -2  \\
a + 0.5b -0.5c &\ge -1 \\ 
-a - 0.5b + 0.5c &\ge 1  \\
a, b, c &\ge 0
\end{align}

However, this dual program does not have a feasible solution, which should be incorrect. Does anyone have any thoughts? Please help me with this.

Comment: I think the primal is unbounded.

Answer (score 1):

Your working seems correct. However, the primal linear program is unbounded, and therefore, by [weak duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_linear_program#Weak_duality), the dual is infeasible.

To see that the primal is unbounded, note that for any $y\le 0$, we can set $$x:=(5-0.5y)/2=2.5-0.25y.$$ Then
\begin{align}
x+y&=2.5-0.25y+y=2.5+0.75y\le 2.5\le 4, \\
2x+0.5y&=5-0.5y+0.5y=5
\end{align}
So $((5-0.5y)/2,y)$ is a feasible solution of the primal for all $y\le 0$. The value of the objective function is $$Z=-2x-y=-5+0.5y-y=-5-0.5y$$ which clearly goes to $+\infty$ as $y\to-\infty$.

Alternatively, you can apply the simplex method to see that the primal is unbounded: you should find a column with negative reduced cost but with no strictly positive entries below it.